# Junit Mockito with spring - test case for the Json String return

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, junit4, mockito, springmockito

I am learning Junit Mockito to test the spring- mvc controller using Spring 3.2 in Intellij.
my controller is

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String initUserSearchForm(ModelMap modelMap) {
        User user = new User();
        modelMap.addAttribute("User", user);
        return "linkedInUser";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/byName", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public
    @ResponseBody
    String getUserByName(HttpServletRequest request,@ModelAttribute("userClientObject") UserClient userClient) {
        String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
        String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");
        return getUserByName(userClient, firstName, lastName);
    }
```

what i have done is i have one form to search the user by name. UserClient Object is a Session Attribute and i tried 
to write a junit test case for my controller

```
 @Test
    public void testInitUserSearchForm() throws Exception {
        this.liClient = client.createUserClient();
        mockMvc.perform(get("/user"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(view().name("user"))
                .andExpect(forwardedUrl("/WEB-INF/pages/user.jsp"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testGeUserByName() throws Exception {
        String firstName = "Wills";
        String lastName = "Smith";         
        mockMvc.perform(get("/user-byName"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());

    }
```

How do I test my `getUserByName` method and how would i add session attribute? Please anyone can help me to 
    write testcase with possible tests for that method. Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the purpose of ",@ModelAttribute("userClientObject") UserClient userClient"

Comment: It is a session attribute when the user login we saved their secret key in session attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmmm.

You could try

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/user-byName").sessionAttr("userClientObject", userClientObject))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

to setup userClientObject in test fixture.

What does "return getUserByName(userClient, firstName, lastName);" exactly do? If it doesn't involve external dependence, just assert your return in andExpect(jsonPath()) clause.

I thought it should be @SessionAttribute by the way.

Comment: It returns the json formated string. How would i test that string is not empty in spring

Comment: Try andExpect(content().string("your json string here"))

Comment: Is it possible to check if content has string instead of equals

Comment: Maybe this helps if you want assert the json string returned. andExpect(jsonPath("fName").exists()//or other convenient method)

Comment: It shows error` java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jayway/jsonpath/InvalidPathException`. Do i need to include any other libraries

Comment: it always null `java.lang.AssertionError: JSON pathfn expected:<Sam> but was:<null>` i used `.andExpect(jsonPath("fn").value("Sam"))`

Comment: Yes, I find the maven gav com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:0.5.5 on the internet.

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362372/testing-with-spring-test-mvc-jsonpath-returns-null maybe helps.

Comment: Is is possible to perform mockito unit test for that above code. I searched in goole but i didn't have idea. Can u help me

Comment: It depends on what's in your getUserByName(userClient, firstName, lastName); is it very complex to setup the test fixture. You might have to post another question to discuss this(due to Stackoverflow rules)

Comment: Hi Hippoom. I posted a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17915828/how-to-write-mockito-test-case.

Answer (score 0):

I use

`mockMvc.perform(get("/user-byName").flashAttr("userClientObject", userClientObject))              .andExpect(status().isOk())`