# How To Write Mockito test case

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, junit4, mockito

I am new to spring and junit. I want to test my controllerusing mockito.I  wrote test case using mock-mvc
but one of my senior told try with mockito. I searched it in google i have no idea about mockito unit testing.

```
@Autowired
private Client client;

 @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String initUserSearchForm(ModelMap modelMap) {
        User user = new User();
        modelMap.addAttribute("User", user);
        return "user";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/byName", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public
    @ResponseBody
    String getUserByName(HttpServletRequest request,@ModelAttribute("userClientObject") UserClient userClient) {
        String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
        String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");
        return client.getUserByName(userClient, firstName, lastName);
    }
```

My mock-mvc test case is

```
@Test
    public void testInitUserSearchForm() throws Exception {
        this.liClient = client.createUserClient();
        mockMvc.perform(get("/user"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(view().name("user"))
                .andExpect(forwardedUrl("/WEB-INF/pages/user.jsp"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testGeUserByName() throws Exception {
        String firstName = "Wills";
        String lastName = "Smith";         
        mockMvc.perform(get("/user-byName"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());

    }
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Could you post your "getUserByName(userClient, firstName, lastName);" implementation code snippet?

Comment: I called getUserByName method from jar. It is an seperate API

Comment: Is it a static method because I don't see an object reference?

Comment: No it is not a static method.I used an jar file of my team mate.

Comment: I don't get it, it should be "someObject.getUserByName()" ?

Comment: yes. I called using some object. See my edited code

Comment: Can you clarify what behaviour you're actually trying to test?  I don't see any code that has any actual logic in it - just things that delegate off to other classes.  Have you shown us the class that you're actually testing?  Trying to unit test any of the code that you've shown here is a waste of time.

Comment: I am trying to test my controller class

Comment: What BEHAVIOUR of your controller class are you trying to test?

Comment: @DavidWallace I want to test my controller using mockito. I need examples for spring mvc controller unit testing with mockito

Comment: So your controller has some kind of specification, right, that says it must do X, Y and Z.  So you have a test that it can do X, and a test that it can do Y and a test that it can do Z.  Drive the test from the specification, not from the finished code.  In your test for behaviour X, you may or may not mock out some other classes that contribute to doing X, depending on whether you are writing a unit test or an integration test.  But if the controller itself doesn't have any logic that contributes to X, there is nothing to test.  The code that you have shown here has no logic; so it makes ...

Comment: ... no sense to test it.  If you have some code with some logic in (branching, looping or exception handling), then show it here, and I will help you work out how to test it.  But for now, there is nothing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Define this client mockito in an xml, let's call it client-mock.xml

```
<bean id="client" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
    <constructor-arg value="your org.Client" /> //interface name
</bean>
```

You might have to add cglib to your classpath if Client is not an interface.

2.Seperate your client "real" from your-servlet-context.xml, so it would not be loaded in tests.

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:your-servlet-context.xml",
    "classpath:client-mock.xml" })
@WebAppConfiguration
public class YourTests {

    @Autowired
    private Client client;

    @Test
    public void testGeUserByName() throws Exception {
        String firstName = "Wills";
        String lastName = "Smith";         
        String returning = //JSON I presume 

        UserClient userClientObject = ;//init

        when(client).getUserByName(userClientObject, firstName, lastName)
        .thenReturn(returning);//define stub call expectation


        mockMvc.perform(get("/user-byName").sessionAttr("userClientObject", userClientObject))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());

    }

}
```

By the way, it doesn't matter whether you use mockito or not if it's not very complex or expensive to use "real" Client in tests.

You can get [Mockito Doc](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/) here.

Comment: org.Client It is a class file. and when i add @ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:META-INF/client-dispatcher-servlet.xml"}) it shows error on test case

Comment: top level element is not completed. I am using intellij

Comment: If i add this `@ContextConfiguration("file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/client-dispatcher-servlet.xml")` it is working fine. i could not add mock.xml

Comment: My problem is when i my mock.xml only it shows error. Whether i need to put an entry in web.xml?

Comment: is it possible to test the view in mockito like` @Test
    public void testInitSorm() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/client/form"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(view().name("user"))
                .andExpect(forwardedUrl("/WEB-INF/pages/user.jsp"));
    }`

Comment: I supoosed to write unit test case similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17969002/spring-controller-testing-with-mockito-and-requestmappinghandlermapping. Please help me to solve the error

Comment: @jackyesind Could you update your question with error stack or any error report?

Comment: Null pointer exception. I asked help for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17969002/spring-controller-testing-with-mockito-and-requestmappinghandlermapping